# .htaccess with strange code

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

So my .htaccess file is looking like this:

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>

    php_value max_execution_time 1800

    # END WordPress

    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Firefox\/40\.1
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-login\.php(.*)$ [OR]
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?xmlrpc\.php(.*)$ [OR]
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-admin(.*)$
    #RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.123\.123\.121$
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=403,L]    

SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Firefox/40.1" tool Deny from env=tool
```

After the # END Wordpress looks pretty strange. I searched google and found that "SetEnvIfNoCase" line shouldn't be there. Is it correct?

Answer (score 2):

Everyone who visits a site leaves behind a trace of how they accessed that website.

For example: Chrome leaves behind `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36`

Some spam bots (automated programs hackers unleash first, to find vulnerable websites and WordPress installations) leave behind a fake trace. (By the way, this trace is called “user-agent”.)

Apparently, this particular web hosting company has suffered a massive attack from a particular spam bot with fake trace identification (“user-agent”) of “Firefox/40.1”. (Firefox never had such a version.)

All the recommended code does is block access to visits with that particular user-agent.